# How many $4$-digit numbers can be formed using digits $0,1,...6$ such that it contains the digits $3$ and $5$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many $4$-digit numbers can be formed using digits $0,1,...6$ such that it contains the digits $3$ and $5$?

My try:

All possible $4$-digit numbers $= 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 6$

$4$-digits numbers NOT containing $3, 5 = 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$

Answer= $7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 6-5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 =1558$

Is that OK ?  If not, please explain my mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: No. If $A$ is "number contains a $3$, and $B$ is "number contains a $5$, then you are looking at event $A\cap B$. The contrary is $\overline{A\cap B}=\overline A\cup \overline B$, and you have to use inclusion-exclusion formula.

Comment: Judging by your attempt, you are assuming the digits may be used with repetition.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig  yes sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is incorrect, because the negation of the statement that the positive integers includes the digits $3$ and $5$ is that it does not contain the digit $3$ or does not contain the digit $5$.  What you subtracted is the number of $4$-digit positive integers that contain neither the digit $3$ nor the digit $5$.  However, numbers such as $3460$ and $2145$ are also inadmissible.

> How many $4$-digit positive integers can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition contain the digits $3$ and $5$?

If there were no restrictions, the thousands place could be filled in six ways (since $0$ is excluded) and each of the three remaining places could be filled in seven ways (assuming repetition of digits is permitted).  Hence, there are a total of $$6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7$$ four-digit positive integers that can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition.

From these, we must subtract those that do not contain the digits $3$ and $5$.  Numbers that do not contain the digits $3$ and $5$ do not contain the digit $3$ or do not contain the digit $5$.

How many four-digit postive integers formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition do not contain the digit $3$?

There are five ways to fill the thousands place (since neither $0$ nor $3$ is permitted) and six ways to fill each of the remaining places (since $3$ is not permitted).  Hence, there are $$5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$$ such numbers.

By symmetry, there are also 
$$5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6$$
four-digit positive integers formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition that do not contain the digit $5$.

However, if we subtract those numbers that do not contain the digit $3$ and those numbers that do not contain the digit $5$ from the total, we will have subtracted those numbers that contain neither the digit $3$ nor the digit $5$ twice.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.

How many four-digit positive integers formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition contain neither the digit $3$ nor the digit $5$?

There are four ways to fill the thousands place (since neither $0$ nor $3$ nor $5$ is permitted) and five ways to fill each of the remaining three places (since neither $3$ nor $5$ is permitted).  Hence, there are 
$$4 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$$ such numbers.

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of positive four-digit positive integers formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition that contain the digits $3$ and $5$ is 
$$6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 - 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$$

More formally, let's follow the suggestion of Nicolas FRANCOIS made in the comments.  Let the universal set, $U$, be the set of four-digit positive integers that may be formed from the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ with repetition; let $A$ be the event that such a four-digit positive integer includes the digit $3$; let $B$ be the event that such a four-digit positive integer includes the digit $5$.  What we wish to calculate is $$|A \cap B| = |U| - |(A \cap B)^C| = |U| - |A^C \cup B^C| = |U| - (|A^C| + |B^C| - |A^C \cap B^C|)$$
What we showed above is that 
\begin{align*}
|U| & = 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7\\
|A^C| & = 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6\\
|B^C| & = 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6\\
|A^C \cap B^C| & = 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5
\end{align*}
which gives 
\begin{align*}
|A \cap B| & = |U| - |(A \cap B)^C|\\
           & = |U| - |A^C \cup B^C|\\
           & = |U| - (|A^C| + |B^C| - |A^C \cap B^C|)\\
           & = |U| - |A^C| - |B^C| + |A^C \cap B^C|\\
           & = 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 - 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 - 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 \cdot 6 + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5\\
           & = 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 \cdot 7 - 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 6\cdot 6 + 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5
\end{align*}

> How many $4$-digit positive integers can be formed using the digits $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ without repetition contain the digits $3$ and $5$?

In this problem, either $3$ or $5$ is the leading digit or neither is.

$3$ or $5$ is the leading digit:

1. Choose which of them is the leading digit.
2. Choose the place occupied by whichever number in the set $\{3, 5\}$ that has not been used as the leading digit.
3. Now that $3$ and $5$ have been placed, choose which of the remaining numbers occupies the first open place.
4. Choose which of the remaining numbers fills the final open place.

> There are $$2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 4$$ such numbers.

Neither $3$ nor $5$ is the leading digit:

1. Choose which of the other non-zero digits occupies the thousands place.
2. Choose which of the remaining places is occupied by the digit $3$.
3. Choose which of the remaining places is occupied by the digit $5$.
4. Choose which of the remaining digits fills the remaining place.

> There are $$4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4$$ such numbers.

Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the answer is found by adding the results for the two cases.

Comment: brilliant answer and explanation ... thank you

Answer (score 2):

You also need to subtract out the number of numbers that contain one or more $5$s but no $3$, as well as the number of numbers that contain one or more $3$s but no $5$.

Or, you can also just count directly:

1. One $3$, one $5$, two something else
2. One $3$, two $5$s, one something else
3. Two $3$s, one $5$, one something else
4. Three $3$s, one $5$
5. Two $3$s, two $5$s
6. One $3$, three $5$s

Answer (score 2):

Since you only care about 4 states: contains neither, contains 3 not 5, contains 5 not 3, contains both; you can use a transition matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
5 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 6 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 7 \end{bmatrix}^3
\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This way, if you wanted to change it to "how many 55 digit numbers..."  all you have to do is change the $3$ in the exponent to a $54$.

Interesting that if you diagonalize the matrix you the same expression as N.G.Taussig's answer: $6 \times 7^3 - 2 \times 5 \times 6^3 + 4 \times 5^3$

Comment: truly fascinated by your unique answer. I wonder if you can put more light into it. Why you constructed it with those values. Thank you +1

Comment: This is no place to fully explain transition matrices, but the idea is that the vector represents "how many for each state" and each application of the matrix to the vector represents the change in the amounts after a transition, in this case the transition is appending another digit to the number.  For for the central matrix $A_{i, j} = z$ means there are $z$ ways to get from state $i$ to state $j$.  $A_{1, 1} = 5$ for example means there are 5 ways to get from a number with no 3,5 to another number with no 3,5, that is by the addition of the digits 0,1,2,4,6 .